# chmod permissions in an ACL folder

Tags: linux, permissions, access-control-list, chmod

I set up a folder managed by ACL, meant to let specific "manager" users have total control over files in it. File access seems ok (e.g. a manager user can delete a file owned by any other user) but managers can't set permissions of files owned by other users with chmod. To be specific:

```
[manager@farm test]$ ll
total 4
-rw-rw----+ 1 root root 0 May  2 08:50 p
[manager@farm test]$ getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:manager:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:manager:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---

[manager@farm test]$ chmod o+w p
chmod: changing permissions of ‘p’: Operation not permitted
```

Do I miss some details in my ACL setup or maybe what I'm trying to do is not allowed at all? Thanks.
Edit: here are some requested details.

1) lsattr output

on NFS server:

```
# lsattr p
------------- p
```

on NFS client:

```
$ lsattr p
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on p
```

2) NFS share mount options:

on server:

```
ext3 rw,noatime,data=ordered,acl 0 0
```

on client:

```
nfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=172.16.1.148,mountvers=3,mountport=773,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=172.16.1.148 0 0
```

3) NFS versions

On server:

```
# rpcinfo -p localhost
program vers proto   port
...
100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
...
```

Comment: check lsattr on this file, if it immune or some other flag is enabled. Also check audit log file and share if you found some related.

Comment: The folder is in an exported NFS share. From client lsattr p gives:
"lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on p"
while from server: " ------------- p" 
About audit, the /var/log/audit/ folder is empty on NFS server, while I don't have access to that folder on client machine.

Comment: can you share nfs version and mount options? NFS having issues with privilege escalation.

Comment: NFS mount options:
172.16.1.148:/wizard/02 /wizard/02 nfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=172.16.1.148,mountvers=3,mountport=773,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=172.16.1.148 0 0

Comment: I am suspecting due to version changes your acl is not working.

Comment: Thanks @asktyagi. So you mean that changing permissions should be possible and that I have a misconfigured system? Specifically, which version change do you refer to?